# How can I save a coordinate into a marker in the new Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I've marked the exact point of a place which I want to save and Google displays the coordinates properly:

[image: Maps]

Is there a way I can save it into a marker to share or access it later?

Comment: It's been 5+ years since this question was posted. Maybe someone know a easier way now.

Comment: @VarunAgw yes indeed, there's a "save" function now in the pop-up panel when you touch a marker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options, depending on what you want to do. Try any one of these:

1. You could just put your coordinates into a URL, like this:

   `https://www.google.com/maps/place/21°31'01.4"N+100°49'43.4"W/`
2. If you use Google+, you can use the "Share" option and share it to a Circle that contains just yourself.
3. Click the "Gear" icon in the lower right, choose "Share and embed map" and you can get a URL that you can share and/or the iframe code to embed the map somewhere.
4. Go to "[My Places](https://www.google.com/maps/mm)" where you should see a recent history of the locations you've used. Click the star next to your coordinates. Now you'll be able to see it under "My Places" > "Starred"
5. Click the pointer, and in the information box that pops up, click the star. This will leave a star on your map you can get back to any time.
6. Under "My Places", choose "Create Map". This launches Google Maps Engine Lite, which lets you create overlays on maps and save them.

Comment: What I've been doing is copying the URL, shortening it with [goo.gl](http://goo.gl) and saving it on [Keep](http://drive.google.com/keep), but the sense is the same: I can't save it directly on Maps. Well, I think I'm stuck with these workarounds.

Comment: @arielnmz: You can save it in "My Places" or use the Maps Engine to save/create a custom map. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. To bad they made it too counter-intuitive in this new version of Maps.

Comment: Another alternative, I believe if your accessing it on the google maps app you can also create a kml file.